# How would you test this action in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I'm a newbie in RSpec, I have this controller in my ruby on rails code

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.build params[:article]
  if @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => 'Article saved successfully!'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

How would you test this action in RSpec ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: How do I mock current_user object ?

Comment: How is generate your current_user too ? Devise/Authlogic/other ?

Comment: I haven't created any model yet, I just want it to pass rspec expectation and every object is a mock object. I imagine this is the code I want and I want to know the best practice to describe it. I have read Pragmatic RSpec book but I'm a bit confuse about how to mock object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    let(:article) { mock_model(Article) }

    before(:each) do
      controller.stub_chain(:current_user,:articles,:build) { article }
    end

    context "success" do
      before(:each) do
        article.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
        post :create
      end

      it "sets flash[:notice]" do
        flash[:notice].should == "Article saved successfully!"
      end

      it "redirects to articles_path" do
        response.should redirect_to(articles_path)
      end

    end

    context "failure" do
      before(:each) do
        article.should_receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create
      end

      it "assigns @article" do
        assigns(:article).should == article
      end

      it "renders new" do
        response.should render_template('new')
      end
    end

  end
```